# Running sqlite script in Sqlite db using C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have some sqlite scripts with some sqlite commands like:

- .headers ON
- .mode CSV           etc.

Is there anyway of running this script in SqliteDB using Sqlite interface for C++, instead of redirecting the file to sqlite using sqlite command line shell?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the result to be the same as running through the shell, or do you want to run them using the API to handle output somehow?

Comment: I need to write the output to a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need the output, than it's by far easiest to just run the script through the command-line shell (it has `-batch` argument to suppress all output except the actual results).

The `.`-commands are implemented in the shell, not the API. Because the API does not do output and the commands you mention are for controlling the output. If you really wanted to run the scripts with the API, you'd need to do the output yourself and either hardcode the format you want or interpret the `.`-commands yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and if so, how to input the script file using the API?

Comment: @DuliniAtapattu: You cannot input the script using the API. If you really want to do it with API (you don't have to, the command-line shell is much easier) you have to read it, split it to commands, create statement (`sqlite3_stmt`) for each and step it through. Or, better, embed the commands in the code.